# Resetting password not working symfony 3

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, forgot-password

I use FOSUserBundle on my symfony 3 project. Evrything is ok but i have ONE problem!!!:-(

when i try reset a password on "I forgot my password", no email sending...Even if, the application redirect user to resetting/check-email view.

Actually i test this on a local server with wamp.

This my configuartion files:

```
#app/paramaters.yml#

mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: adress@gmail.com
mailer_password: ********

#app/config.yml#

# Swiftmailer Configuration

swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }

#FriendsOfSymfonyBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MA\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
            address: adress@gmail.com
            sender_name: Admin
    service:
            mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
            confirmation:
                from_email:
                    address:        adress@gmail.com
                    sender_name:    Admin
    resetting:
            email:
                from_email:
                    address:        adress@gmail.com
                    sender_name:    Admin
```

Somebody can help me??please!!

Comment: Can you see your email in the profiler?  {yourappdomain}/_profiler

Comment: No i can't! In the profiler, the email is empty...

Comment: Any idea, please??

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve it changing the mailing transport on parameters.yml to "mail"

```
mailer_transport: mail
```